# Initialize a vector to save memory in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I read that initialization of vectors <s>saves memory</s> speeds up execution time when running code in matlab, however I do not know how to do that in this case.

I have a vector that I reuse and adds onto itself in a loop, so I should preallocate a vector that has the length of the ending vector. I have tried

```
vec=zeros(1,n)
```

but that tacks on zeros to the start of the output matrix.

```
clc
clear
n=6
x=0
vec=x
    for i=1:n
        x=x+1
        vec=[vec,x]
    end
vec
```

Is there another way to initialize the 'vec' vector?

Now changed to:

```
clc
clear
n=6
x=0
vec=zeros(1,n) %changed from x=0
    for i=1:n
        x=x+1 
        vec(i)=x %changed from   vec=[vec,x]
    end
vec
```

Comment: Is this a bad question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As also mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85254), this can be simply done as:  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  ‍‍‍‍‍‍  `vec = 0:6`

You wrote,*"I read that initialization of vectors saves memory when running code".*

This statement is not correct. Always refer to the documentation for getting the correct information.
The following is written in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html):

> "`for` and `while` loops that incrementally increase the size of a
>   data structure each time through the loop can adversely affect
>   performance and memory use. Repeatedly resizing arrays often requires
>   MATLAB® to spend extra time looking for larger contiguous blocks of
>   memory, and then moving the array into those blocks. Often, you can
>   improve code execution time by preallocating the maximum amount of
>   space required for the array."

So this is not about *saving memory*. This is about *improving memory usage* and *execution time*.

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize it as an empty array and just concatenate to it. Matlab allows that, though not sure how good of a practice it is to do that. Also not sure why you're initializing a zero array and then concatenating x values onto it. Are you trying to set index 1 as the first x value, index 2 as the 2nd x value, etc?

Comment: Yeah, I should instead set the output to index values. Didn't think of that, thanks.

Comment: Ah ok. So in that case, your initialization is fine, just do vec[i] = x;

Comment: vec(i)=x sets values to the indices. What would vec[i] reference to? Thanks for the fast answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant vec(i). vec[i] should throw an error.

Comment: Initializing an empty array and then changing the size of an array in a loop is a [bad practice](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html).

Comment: Thanks, I see why now. But just to check, I shouldn't do it because it increases the time taken to process script?

Comment: both answers answer my question